# Erro: argumento 'envir' numérico não tem comprimento um

Tags: r, machine-learning

Estou tentando verificar a probabilidade do sorteio do numero 5 em um jogo de bingo.

Gostaria de algumas dicas para quem está iniciando. Talvez a função `lm` não seja a ideal para este problema.

O programa inicial é simples:

```
setwd("d:\\Bingo.R")

cartela = 1:25

numerosSorteados <- c(1,2,3,4)

modelo <- lm(formula = cartela$v1 ~ numerosSorteados, data=cartela)
```

Estou recebendo o erro abaixo:

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
>     argumento 'envir' numérico não tem comprimento um

Alguém poderia me explicar o que seria este erro?

Obs: meu ambiente está setado para ingles mas as mensagens saem misturadas entre inglês e português.

Answer (score 5):

Antes, duas definições:

- Um vetor é uma coleção de *n* elementos do mesmo tipo.
- A função `lm` significa *linear model* (modelo linear). Simplificando muito, em sua versão mais simples, o que ela faz é ajustar a melhor reta possível a dois vetores.

Tome, por exemplo, o conjunto de dados `cars`. Ele possui observações sobre a velocidade e a distância que carros levaram para parar completamente a partir de terem os freios acionados. São 50 linhas e duas colunas, totalizando 100 observações. Cada carro contribui com duas delas: uma para a velocidade e outra para a distância. Veja que é possível plotar estas observações em um gráfico:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A função `lm` vai servir para ajustar uma reta a estes dados:

```
ajuste <- lm(dist ~ speed, data = cars)
summary(ajuste)

Call:
lm(formula = dist ~ speed, data = cars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-29.069  -9.525  -2.272   9.215  43.201 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -17.5791     6.7584  -2.601   0.0123 *  
speed         3.9324     0.4155   9.464 1.49e-12 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 15.38 on 48 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6511,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6438 
F-statistic: 89.57 on 1 and 48 DF,  p-value: 1.49e-12


abline(ajuste)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que, para usar a função `lm`, obrigatoriamente é necessário que `dist` e `speed` tenham o mesmo tamanho:

```
length(cars$dist)
[1] 50
length(cars$speed)
[1] 50
```

No teu caso, isso não acontece:

```
length(cartela)
[1] 25
length(numerosSorteados)
[1] 4
```

Além disso, `cartela$v1` não existe:

```
length(cartela$v1)
Error in cartela$v1 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Portanto, a melhor maneira de responder a pergunta "verificar a probabilidade do sorteio do numero 5 em um jogo de bingo" é criando uma tabela de frequências e calculando as probabilidades de cada número sair:

```
prop.table(table(numerosSorteados))
numerosSorteados
   1    2    3    4 
0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
```

No caso, as probabilidades de 1, 2, 3 e 4 são as mesmas, iguais a 0.25 (ou 25%). Todos os outros números da cartela tem probabilidade igual a zero de serem escolhidos, pois nunca foram sorteados.